# Can display a variable on onclick event in html or c#.

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Can I display a variable on onclick event in html or c#. I called alert(string) on onclick event but string was not displayed. I am making a shopping cart in which I have made a class for cart in c#. On clicking of button I want to display all the selected items and qty for which i am calling `cart.stratc` method on `onclickevent` which prepares the message string for selected item.i am not able to display string `cartstr`.

Comment: Show some code you have written so we can get some idea of how you are trying this?

Comment: your question is too general and there are lots of ways to do them; for example if you just want to alert a public property in the page you can just use alert('<%= myVariable %>');

Comment: I am using webmatrix and I have declared class in .cs file.class is:

Comment: Can you post some code where you tried?

Answer (score 0):

The click event needs to use the runat="server".
 
This will invoke your code behind method and in the code behind reference another control like a text box that is defined on the page to display the results

The text box control must also be defined as an asp server control.

Comment: I want to display commodities selected in checkboxes here in cshtml file: <button id="button1"  onclick="var0.stratc">add to cart</button>
                                 @ObjectInfo.Print(var0.stratc)
                                 <h2>@var1</h2>